# Debugging current file in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am writing javascript and am currently doing simple exercises/programs.  At times, I wish to run my file for testing purposes.  I am aware I could create an `HTML` file and do this within the console.  In Sublime, there exists a way to "build" the current file and immediately see the results (say, whatever is sent to console.log).

With VS Code, it seems that for every file I want to "build"/debug in this manner, I must manually change the `launch.json` file to reflect the name of the current program.

I have been researching a way around this, and I learned that there are variables like `${file}` , but when I use that in the `launch.json` "program" attribute, for example:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/${file}"
```

with or without the `workspaceRoot` part, I get the following error:

```
Attribute "program" does not exist" (file name here).
```

Am I missing a simple way to accomplish this, or must I keep editing `launch.json` every time I want to run the file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thinks this one has an update. Now we can just debug a js file directly by pressing the debug start button. Unless there is a config already there. It starts debugging current file automatically.

Answer (score 196):

Change to:

```
"program": "${file}"
```

Comment: I use different names to debug different files in the project and delete the entry from launch.json file once I'm done.

Comment: @jdb79 You should accept the answer by clicking the green tick on the left

Comment: I also added on occasion `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` to make it start in the current file's folder (useful for instance when loading files using a relative path to the current file's location - eg: `fs.readFile('./somefile.txt')`)

Comment: and there's more: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Comment: I'm doing this but whenever I press F5 it opens the current file in a new readonly editor tab.

Answer (score 74):

For reference this is the full launch.json

```
{
  "launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Node.js - Debug Current File",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In my project's launch.json there is entry "name": "Launch Program", will it make difference instead of "Debug File" use "Launch Program" ?

Comment: @vikramvi no difference, it is only for reference (eg it will show in status bar the name of current active task)

Comment: What makes a diff is `type` I think: you can have similar configuration objects, but having diffs in the `name` and `type` keys. `type` is the language.

Answer (score 10):

There are many different ways you may need to access a file that are provided by  [**Predefined variables**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference):

> Supposing that you have the following requirements:
>
> - A file located at `/home/your-username/your-project/folder/file.ext` opened in your editor;
> - The directory `/home/your-username/your-project` opened as your root workspace.
>
> So you will have the following values for each variable:
>
> - **`${userHome}`** - `/home/your-username`
> - **`${workspaceFolder}`** - `/home/your-username/your-project`
> - **`${workspaceFolderBasename}`** - `your-project`
> - **`${file}`** - `/home/your-username/your-project/folder/file.ext`
> - **`${fileWorkspaceFolder}`** - `/home/your-username/your-project`
> - **`${relativeFile}`** - `folder/file.ext`
> - **`${relativeFileDirname}`** - `folder`
> - **`${fileBasename}`** - `file.ext`
> - **`${fileBasenameNoExtension}`** - `file`
> - **`${fileDirname}`** - `/home/your-username/your-project/folder`
> - **`${fileExtname}`** - `.ext`
> - **`${lineNumber}`** - line number of the cursor
> - **`${selectedText}`** - text selected in your code editor
> - **`${execPath}`** - location of Code.exe
> - **`${pathSeparator}`** - `/` on macOS or linux, `\` on Windows

Answer (score 1):

For a single file, you can skip the launch.json file entirely. Just click the green arrow in the debugger panel and choose Node as your environment.

From [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/debugging).

Comment: If you have no launch config setup yet, then clicking the green arrow will give you a choice of environments and then create the launch file with an item in it. Otherwise, the green arrow will run the selected item in the droplist.

Comment: Or just press F5

Comment: Re @MichaelCurrin -- looks like a package.json with a main or bin entry may also force running the file listed there, not the active one in VS Code.